# Circular dependency in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a big problem here.

I have a computed variable that gets updated after a change in an observable array.

The problem is that after the computed variable is evaluated, I need to change the observable array values using the new computed value.

How can I do this?

My first approach was to create a function that would subscribe to the computed variable and make all the necessary changes to the observable there. Problem? That would cause the observable to get updated again and this would notify the computed again.

I have a circular dependency.

I have no idea how to solve this.

Any ideas please ?

Comment: Can you post your code? I'm really confused why a computed would *want* to update one of its dependencies. That just sounds wrong.

Comment: yes post code.  Often, circular dependencies are a design error.

Comment: Knockoutjs has precautions against circular references, so it just works out of the box, see: http://jsfiddle.net/mPpcR/1/. But it depends on your actual calculations if the result is *correct*.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this kind of problem, using subscribe. I had two observable array with each having observable in them. I have subscribed one to other and it worked for me. Here is sample on how to subscribe through observable arrays..

```
self.teams.subscribe(function() {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.teams(), function(item) {
                item.player.subscribe(function(newValue) {
                    if (self.teams() != "" && self.teams() != null) {
                        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.GroupofTeams(), function (team) {
                            ..........code.....
                        });
                    } 
                });
            });
        });
```